# Mapping/ Lookup for list type column

Tags: pandas, mapping

I want to create a new column (not in required in form of a list) 'also_view_brand' that will take values of 'also_view' mapped with 'brand'. How to do this?

```
| asin | brand | also_view
| B0001 | Apple | [] 
| B0004  | Samsung | [B0001, B00002, B0003]   
| B0002  | OnePlus | [B0001, B0004]  
| B0003 | Motorola | [B0002, B0004]
```

I couldn't find anything of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a dictionary from 'asin' and 'brand' (provided it's 1-to-1 mapping) and look up the value in the dictionary from the key in 'also_view'

```
mapping = dict(zip(df['asin'], df['brand']))
# depend on how you want value to be returned if key not in dictionary
df['also_view_brand'] = df['also_view'].apply(lambda x: [mapping.get(i, 'Not Exist') for i in x])
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks a ton ! I have a continuing question though. What can I do to ignore the 'Not Exist' entries and have only the ones which got mapped. If you could help on this too.

Comment: df['also_view_brand'] = df['also_view'].apply(lambda x: [mapping.get(i) for i in x if i in mapping])